# how can create User Control static

Tags: static, controls

Good afternoon everyone, someone could help me in the following situation:

I am creating some custom components in VS, but I need to add a component with no information, only to use their form to add some objects in real time depending on user actions. 
It turns out that when I add a control in real time, this control is added to an instance of this object, and is not visible to the user.

Is there any way to make this object of static form? all changes made, is affected in all objects used?

I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ALL,

I created a static class and added a panel of static form, used the panel on the form and changed its ownership dock = fill with all the objects that it adds the panel were updated in form!